# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Cannot find any information on property 'name' in a bean of type 'jsp.SetAndGetUser'

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans, jsp-tags

I have leaning jsp set and get action tag using java bean and get the error. Any solution please..

this is my index form to take the imput.

```
     form action="setAndGet_process.jsp" method="post">

    Name:<input type="text" name="name"><br> 
    Password:<input type="password" name="password"><br> 
    Email:<input type="text" name="email"><br>
     <input type="submit" value="Register">

    </form>
```

Jsp process code the handle the input

```
         <jsp:useBean id="u" class="jsp.SetAndGetUser"></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="u" />

Records:
<br>

<jsp:getProperty property="name" name="u" /><br>
<jsp:getProperty property="password" name="u" /><br>
<jsp:getProperty property="email" name="u" /><br>
```

and java last one is java user bean for setter and getter

```
     package jsp;
   public class SetAndGetUser {
private String name, password, email;
```

}

Comment: if possible please tell me the directory structure. I am using eclipse ide.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your class "SetAndGetUser"

```
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }


    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }


    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Jairo: I have googled and find the answer here  Thanks http://www.concretepage.com/forum/thread?qid=426